# Powershell Using Get-Date in a string to print in a txt file

Tags: powershell

In powershell if I run `Get_Date` by itself it will give me the correct date. But in my script when I run

`"$computer" + "_Already_Had_Software_" + "(Get-Date)" | Out-File -FilePath "\\server\Install\Office2010\RemoteInstallfile.txt" -Append`

It does not show the date but just says

```
_Already_Had_Software_Get-Date
```

Instead of showing the actual date.

Will someone please tell me where I may be going wrong?

Comment: `"$computer" + "_Already_Had_Software_" + "$(Get-Date)" ` You need to use a subexpression with your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `"$(Get-Date)"`. Your string forgot the `$` that tells powershell to execute it.

Alternates:

1. `"${computer}_Already_Had_Software_$(Get-Date)"`
2. `"$computer" + "_Already_Had_Software_" + (Get-Date)`
3. `({0}_Already_Had_Software_{1} -f $computer, (Get-Date))`
4. `[String]::Join('_', ($computer, 'Already_Had_Software', (Get-Date)))`

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd --- hh-mm-ss-fff tt Zone K" | Out-String
"$computer" + "_Already_Had_Software_" + "$date" | Out-File -FilePath "\\server\Install\Office2010\RemoteInstallfile.txt" -Append
```